# Create or update object in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a new object if it not exist; Or just update its email if it already exist in my database.
I import my data from a CSV files.

I tried to use `find_or_create_by` method but still duplicate the object in the database when it already exist. It do not just update it.

Person.rb

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :email,  uniqueness: true
   require 'csv'

   def self.import_data
     filename = File.join Rails.root, '/vendor/people.csv'

     CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, col_sep: ',') do  |row|
       firstname, lastname, home_phone_number, mobile_phone_number,   email, address = row
       Person.find_or_create_by(firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], email: row['email'], address: row['address'])
     end
   end
 end
```

schema.rb

```
   create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email"
t.string   "home_phone_number"
t.string   "mobile_phone_number"
t.string   "firstname"
t.string   "lastname"
t.string   "address"
t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
person = Person.find_or_create_by(firstname: row["firstname"])
person.update_attributes({firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], address: row['address'], email: row['email']})
```

I can't explain why this solution is working and not the one you proposed to me.
But thanks @sohail_khalil and @abhilash for your help !

Comment: While this answer does solve the issue at hand...the approach is bound to fail eventually...there are too many "John Smith" etc... in this world. @sohailkhalil was correct in that the query should be based on a unique column. If email could be updated, there should be a column in CSV for `"last_email"` or something to that effect...

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this

```
Person.find_or_create_by(email: row['email']) do |person|
  person.update_attributes(firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], address: row['address'])
end
```

What you was doing wrong is you apply find_or_create_by on multiple columns. Apply it to only one.

I hope this will help you and will solve your problem.

Comment: I also tried your method and I get the same error.  
I made the `find_or_create` method on firstname and lastname as the email is the attribute which is able to be changed. But as firstname and lastname aldready exists it doesn't go into the loop to update the email. However, It works fine when the object does not exists and as to be create.

Comment: there is not validation on firstname and lastname. How you get the exact record with firstname and lastname. Find some other unique field from which you will get the exact record and update the email. Now the only email is the unique attribute.

Comment: Sorry but there is something I do not understand. The email field is the only one which may be updated by users. So if I do the `find_or_create` with the email it can't find the corresponding object because it's a new email, so it will create a new object. And if I do the  `find_or_create`  on the firstname it will not update it because firstname does already exist and it doesn't go in the loop... I'm a little bit lost sorry !

Comment: @Orsay the approach is bound to fail eventually...there are too many "John Smith" etc... in this world. @sohailkhalil was correct in that the query should be based on a unique column. If email could be updated, there should be a column in CSV for `"last_email"` or something to that effect...

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the problem stated! The block only gets executed in case of create. If the record already exists and is found, the block is not executed and will not be updated!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @sohail said. In order to user multiple parameters to find a record and subsequently update or create you can use

```
Person.where(<conditions>).first_or_initialize do |person|
   <initialize code>
end
```

That should do it.

Comment: I made the `where` method on `firstname` and `lastname` as the email is the attribute which is able to be changed.
But as firstname and lastname aldready exists it doesn't go into the loop to update the email.

However, It works fine when the object does not exists and as to be create.

Answer (score -2):

If you have Rails 3.2 or higher then replace:

```
 Person.find_or_create_by(firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], email: row['email'], address: row['address'])
```

with:

```
Person.where(:email => row['email']).first_or_create(:firstname => row['firstname'], :lastname => row['lastname'], :home_phone_number => row['home_phone_number'], :mobile_phone_number => row['mobile_phone_number'], :email => row['email'], :address => row['address'])
```

Comment: This will not update an existing record. OP wants to update attributes if the record already exists. First or create uses an `OR`  - so this will create if it doesn't exist, but only return what already exists...